# Rails: How to rollback active record inside a with_lock block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, postgresql-9.3

I want to rollback transactions inside a `with_lock` when the condition match. I tried `raise ActiveRecord::Rollback` but it won't worked and records are still created. Here is the short version of my code.

```
object.with_lock do
 a = num
 for i in [1..10] do 
  unless obj1.tickets.create(params)
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
  a += 1
 end

 unless obj2.update_attributes(a: a) ## I tried 'if' in place of 'unless' for test
   raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
 end
end
```

**EDIT1**

This is what worked for me

```
object.with_lock do
 ActiveRecord::Base.transaction(requires_new: true) do
  a = num
  for i in [1..10] do 
   unless obj1.tickets.create(params)
     raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
   end
   a += 1
  end

  unless obj2.update_attributes(a: a)
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Raising rollback works inside a transaction like this.](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Rollback.html)

```
ApplicationRecord.transaction
  # ...
  unless obj1.tickets.create(params)
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "Call tech support!"
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried `Model.transaction` inside the `with_lock` but not worked and then tried this `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction(requires_new: true)` and it worked . Is it because the obj1 is object of another Model?  Anyways thanx, I can proceed now.

Comment: I updated the answer to use `ApplicationRecord` instead